# BigQuery use_avro_logical_types ignored in Python script

Tags: python, google-bigquery, avro

I'm trying to load AVRO files to BigQuery using a Python script. This process itself succeeds, but I'm having some trouble getting BigQuery to use AVRO's logical data types during table creation.

Using these logical types is documented by Google [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types) and was added to the google-cloud-python libraries [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/6827).

I'm not a coder by profession but I'd expect below snippet to be correct... The use_avro_logical_types property however, seems to be ignored and timestamps are loaded as INT instead of TIMESTAMP.

```
...    
with open(full_name, 'rb') as source_file:
           var_job_config = google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig()
           var_job_config.source_format = 'AVRO'
           var_job_config.use_avro_logical_types = True
           job = client.load_table_from_file(
               source_file, table_ref, job_config=var_job_config)
        job.result()  # Waits for job to complete
...
```

The AVRO schema is as follows:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "table_test",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "id_",
        "type": {
            "type": "bytes",
            "logicalType": "decimal",
            "precision": 29,
            "scale": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "datetime_",
        "type": ["null",
        {
            "type": "long",
            "logicalType": "timestamp-micros"
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "integer_",
        "type": ["null",
        {
            "type": "bytes",
            "logicalType": "decimal",
            "precision": 29,
            "scale": 0
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "varchar_",
        "type": ["null",
        {
            "type": "string",
            "logicalType": "varchar",
            "maxLength": 60
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "capture_time",
        "type": {
            "type": "long",
            "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "op_type",
        "type": "int"
    },
    {
        "name": "seq_no",
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "logicalType": "varchar",
            "maxLength": 16
        }
    }]
}
```

Can anyone elaborate on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the avro schema of your data?  I'd like to confirm the logical type annotations for the timestamp column(s).

Comment: @shollyman added!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently my Python libs weren't as up-to-date as I thought.. updating my Google Cloud libs solved the issue. Thanks for your input [shollyman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212435/shollyman)

Comment: Perfect, solved it for me too. Don't forget to accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct, and the logical type annotations look correct as well. I see that you have both milli and micro precisions, but I don't believe that will matter in this case.

One possibility:  Are you writing to an existing table?  As written, the code sample will use an `APPEND` write disposition as its the default for load jobs.  In this case, the load may be adapting the schema to what's defined (e.g. the table was initially created with the columns as INTEGER rather than TIMESTAMP).  You should be able to test by directing the load to a nonexistent table, or possibly using a truncate write disposition to allow overwriting the table.

```
var_job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
```

Comment: I was manually deleting the table from the GUI. I also tried your solution, but no change unfortunately. Uploading the same file using the CLI and property works fine..

Comment: That's unusual.  I [adapted your sample](https://gist.github.com/shollyman/67cb927ad4af72afd8f9e85a70805655) and was able to use it successfully.  Would you please file an issue on the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with the project and a sample job ID that demonstrates this?