# BigQuery - use_avro_logical_types doesn´t work in a python script

Tags: python, google-bigquery, avro

The doubt is similar to the question: [BigQuery use_avro_logical_types ignored in Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242116/bigquery-use-avro-logical-types-ignored-in-python-script) however I have already updated the libraries I use google without success. So I would like to understand what is happening in my case. I will send the intake script part of the avro file. Note: The issue occurs in more than one avro file ingestion pipeline for BigQuery.

EDIT: The mentioned solution of changing schema type didn't work, it gave another error.

Schema in BQ:

[image]

Data in BQ:

[image]

```
import csv
import base64
import json
import io
import avro.schema
import avro.io
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
import math
import os
import gcloud
from gcloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import numpy as np

try:
    script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/"
except:
    script_path = "C:\\Users\\me\\key.json"

#Bigquery Credentials and settings
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = script_path

folder = str((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
data_folder = str((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
bucket_name = 'gs://bucket/*.csv'
dataset = 'dataset'
tabela = 'table_ids'

new_file = 'C:\\Users\\me\\register_' + data_folder + '.avro'
file_schema = 'C:\\Users\\me\\schema.avsc'
new_filename = 'register_' + data_folder + '.avro'

bq1 = bigquery.Client()
#Deleta IDs
query1 = """DELETE FROM dataset.table_ids WHERE ID IS NOT NULL""" 
query_job1 = bq1.query(query1)

def insert_bigquery(target_uri, dataset_id, table_id):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('id','STRING',mode='REQUIRED')
    ]
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.field_delimiter = ";"
    uri = target_uri
    load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        dataset_ref.table(table_id),
        job_config=job_config
        )
    print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    load_job.result()
    print('Job finished.')

insert_bigquery(bucket_name, dataset, tabela)

def get_data_from_bigquery():
    """query bigquery to get data to import to PSQL"""
    bq = bigquery.Client()
    #Busca IDs
    query = """SELECT id FROM dataset.table_ids"""
    query_job = bq.query(query)
    data = query_job.result()
    rows = list(data)
    return rows

a = get_data_from_bigquery()
length = len(a) 
line_count = 0
schema = avro.schema.Parse(open(file_schema, "rb").read())  # need to know the schema to write. According to 1.8.2 of Apache Avro
writer = DataFileWriter(open(new_file, "wb"), avro.io.DatumWriter(), schema)

for row in range(length):
    bytes = base64.b64decode(str(a[row][0]))
    bytes = bytes[5:]
    buf = io.BytesIO(bytes)
    decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(buf)
    rec_reader = avro.io.DatumReader(avro.schema.Parse(open(file_schema).read()))
    out=rec_reader.read(decoder)
    writer.append(out)
writer.close()

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob("insert/" + destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    print('File {} uploaded to {}'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name
    ))

upload_blob('bucket', new_file, new_filename)

def insert_bigquery_avro(target_uri, dataset_id, table_id):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.AVRO
    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    job_config.use_avro_logical_types = True
    time_partitioning = bigquery.table.TimePartitioning()
    job_config.time_partitioning = time_partitioning
    uri = target_uri
    load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        dataset_ref.table(table_id),
        job_config=job_config
        )
    print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    load_job.result()
    print('Job finished.')
```

Avro Schema:

```
"fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      },
      "doc": "the payment id"
    },
    {
      "name": "merchant",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      },
      "doc": "the merchant who owns the payment"
    },
    {
      "name": "date",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      },
      "doc": "the date where the transaction happend"
    },
    {
      "name": "amount",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "amount",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "amount",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 5,
                "scale": 5
              }
            ],
            "doc": "the original currency amount",
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "foreignAmount",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 5,
                "scale": 5
              }
            ],
            "doc": "the foreign amount for the payment",
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "code",
            "type": {
              "type": "string",
              "avro.java.string": "String"
            },
            "doc": "the destination currency code"
          }
        ],
        "default": null
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "exchange_rate",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "code",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "currency_code",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "doc": "the exchange rate currency code",
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "rate",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 5,
                "scale": 5
              }
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "online_rate",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 5,
                "scale": 5
              }
            ],
            "default": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "doc": "The transaction exchange rate"
    },
    {
      "name": "consumer",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Consumer",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "doc": "the consumer's name",
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "email",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "doc": "the consumer's email address",
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "external_id",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "doc": "the consumer's external id when needed",
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "national_id",
            "type": {
              "type": "string",
              "avro.java.string": "String"
            },
            "doc": "the national id"
          },
          {
            "name": "phone",
            "type": {
              "type": "string",
              "avro.java.string": "String"
            },
            "doc": "the consumer's phone number",
            "default": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "soft_descriptor",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "string",
          "avro.java.string": "String"
        }
      ],
      "doc": "the description as it will be shown at the customer's invoice",
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "merchant_contract",
      "type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "merchant_contract_type",
        "symbols": [
          "PAY",
          "BANK"
        ]
      },
      "default": "PAY"
    },
    {
      "name": "type",
      "type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "payment_type",
        "symbols": [
          "INITIAL",
          "CREDIT_CARD",
          "DEBIT_CARD",
          "ONLINE_DEBIT",
          "BANK_SLIP",
          "DIGITAL_WALLET",
          "ELECTRONIC_BANK_TRANSFER"
        ]
      },
      "default": "INITIAL"
    },
    {
      "name": "card",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "card",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "type",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "card_type",
                "symbols": [
                  "CARD",
                  "TOKEN"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "mask_number",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "card_holder",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "brand",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "default": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "confirm",
      "type": "boolean",
      "doc": "indicates whether is self confirmed",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "name": "installments",
      "type": "int",
      "doc": "Number of installments for the payment",
      "default": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "due_date",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "int",
          "logicalType": "date"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "correlation_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "string",
          "avro.java.string": "String"
        }
      ],
      "doc": "the external customer correlationid",
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "billing",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Billing",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "national_id",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "doc": "billing info",
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            ],
            "doc": "the consumer address name",
            "default": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "status",
      "type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "payment_status",
        "symbols": [
          "INITIAL",
          "CONSUMER",
          "AUTHORIZED",
          "WAITING_CONFIRMATION",
          "CANCELED",
          "WAITING_CLEARING",
          "CLEARED",
          "TRANSFERENCE",
          "DECLINED_BY_ISSUER",
          "DECLINED_BY_BUSINESS_RULES",
          "CONFIRMED",
          "WAITING_CANCELING",
          "WAITING_CONSUMER",
          "TRANSFER_REQUESTED"
        ],
        "default": "INITIAL"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": {
          "type": "string",
          "avro.java.string": "String"
        },
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "events",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "event",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              },
              "default": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "type",
              "type": {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "event_type",
                "symbols": [
                  "AUTHORIZATION",
                  "AUTHENTICATION",
                  "CONFIRMATION",
                  "CANCELATION",
                  "CHECKOUT_CREATION",
                  "SETTLEMENT",
                  "TRANSFER_VALIDATION",
                  "TRANSFER_SCHEDULE",
                  "TRANSFERRED"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "gateway",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "string",
                  "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
              ],
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "breadcrumb_id",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "string",
                  "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
              ],
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "request_time",
              "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
              },
              "doc": "the moment where this request was received by the platform"
            },
            {
              "name": "response_time",
              "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
              },
              "doc": "the moment where this request was returned by the platform"
            },
            {
              "name": "status",
              "type": {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "event_status",
                "symbols": [
                  "SUCCESS",
                  "DENIED",
                  "ERROR",
                  "TIMEOUT",
                  "PENDING"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "actor",
              "type": {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "actor",
                "symbols": [
                  "AQ",
                  "GTW",
                  "CONCIL"
                ],
                "default": "GTW"
              },
              "default": "GTW"
            },
            {
              "name": "amount",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "bytes",
                  "logicalType": "decimal",
                  "precision": 5,
                  "scale": 5
                }
              ],
              "doc": "the original currency amount",
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "foreign_amount",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "bytes",
                  "logicalType": "decimal",
                  "precision": 5,
                  "scale": 5
                }
              ],
              "doc": "the foreign amount for the payment",
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "error",
              "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Error",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "code",
                    "type": [
                      "null",
                      {
                        "type": "string",
                        "avro.java.string": "String"
                      }
                    ],
                    "default": null
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "message",
                    "type": [
                      "null",
                      {
                        "type": "string",
                        "avro.java.string": "String"
                      }
                    ],
                    "default": null
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "message",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "string",
                  "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
              ],
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "fee_amount",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "bytes",
                  "logicalType": "decimal",
                  "precision": 5,
                  "scale": 5
                }
              ],
              "doc": "the fee amount",
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "net_amount",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "bytes",
                  "logicalType": "decimal",
                  "precision": 5,
                  "scale": 5
                }
              ],
              "doc": "the net amount",
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "metadata",
              "type": {
                "type": "map",
                "values": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "avro.java.string": "String"
                },
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "internal_metadata",
              "type": {
                "type": "map",
                "values": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "avro.java.string": "String"
                },
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "bank_account",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "bank_account",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "name",
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              },
              "doc": "the bank name",
              "default": ""
            },
            {
              "name": "code",
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              },
              "doc": "the bank code",
              "default": ""
            },
            {
              "name": "agency",
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              },
              "doc": "the bank agency",
              "default": ""
            },
            {
              "name": "account",
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              },
              "doc": "the bank account",
              "default": ""
            },
            {
              "name": "document_number",
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
              },
              "doc": "the bank document number (CNPJ)",
              "default": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "doc": "The bank account values",
      "default": null
    }
  ]
```

Comment: 1. Could you post the resulting schema of your BigQuery table after the load job finished?
2. Are you trying to load to an existing table (then which writing mode did you use, WRITE_APPEND or WRITE_TRUNCATE), or are you loading into a new table.
3. Which column(s) gave you the type that you were not expecting it to be?

Comment: @NhanNguyen Hello, I just included the requested information. If the table doesn't exist, the idea is that it generates a table but it's all on top of a WRITE_APPEND. The columns that should be changed: date (timestamp), due_date (date), response_time (timestamp), request_time (timestamp).

Comment: @NhanNguyen Do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this as "type" for all timestamps columns on your avro schema:

```
"type": ["null", {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}]
```

Comment: I tried but, i receive this message: Can't access branch index 1574092545874 for union with 2 branches
Writer's Schema: [
  "null",
  {
    "type": "long",
    "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
  }
]
Reader's Schema: [
  "null",
  {
    "type": "long",
    "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
  }
]

Comment: Could you provide your schema?

Comment: I see you also have date types, so my previous suggestion won't work. please refer to this [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/35905894) and [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/6827)